# ConTeXt: Retrieve caption of referenced figure

Tags: cross-referencing, context

The title pretty much says it...

I would like to retrieve the caption of a figure I placed earlier in the document.

```
\starttext
\placefigure[][fig:foo]{My caption}{\externalfigure[foo.png]}

\input knuth

\getcaption{fig:foo} %Output: My caption
\stoptext
```

Comment: Ups, thought it would be easier and the caption stored in some sort of data structure. In that case I'm way out of my depth

Comment: Is it possible to code this in lua?

Comment: @Christoph The reference for a float goes into the second optional argument and not the first like you have it in your example. Even when you don’t have a placement option you need the first optional argument when you add a reference, e.g. `\placefigure[][fig:foo]{...}{...}`.

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster Thank you, I just corrected it

Comment: @Christoph: You can also use `\startplacefigure[reference=fig:foo, location=..., title=....] \externalfigure[...] \stopplacefigure`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show the text of a float title or a section header with the `\about` command. Another way is to use the `\getreference` command with the `title` keyword.

To remove the quotation marks from the `\about` command change the values of the `left` and `right` keys of the `\setupreferencing` command.

```
\useMPlibrary[dum]

% \setupreferencing[left=,right=]

\starttext

\placefigure[][fig:foo]{My caption}{\externalfigure[foo.png]}

\samplefile{knuth}

\starttabulate
\NC \tex{about}        \EQ \about[fig:foo]               \NC\NR
\NC \tex{getreference} \EQ \getreference[title][fig:foo] \NC\NR
\stoptabulate

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I saw those macros in the Wiki when I looked for my answer, but couldn't use it properly. I found definedataset only later on.

Answer (score 2):

Digging into [ConTeXt wiki](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/System_Macros/Key_Value_Assignments) helped me found an answer using datasets

```
%create a data set with figure captions
\definedataset[Captions]

%macro that will place figure and store its caption data
\def\Myfigure#1#2#3{%
    %title is store in Captions data set under the figure label key
    \setdataset[Captions][#1][caption=#2]
    \placefigure[#1]{#2}{#3}
}
\def\Getcaption#1{%
   %call for dataset with the figure label
   \datasetvariable{Captions}{#1}{caption} 
}
\starttext
\Myfigure{fig:foo}{a retrievable caption}{\externalfigure[cow]}

\input knuth

\bf \Getcaption{fig:foo}
\stoptext
```

[image: compilation output]

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I needed. And much more beautiful than Lua ;-)